# MYSQL indexing rownum reverse order

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a query similar to the above.

```
idx   | rownum
1     | 10
2     | 9
3     | 8
4     | 7
5     | 6
6     | 5
7     | 4
8     | 3
9     | 2
10    | 1
```

Comment: Any attempts to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On versions of MySQL earlier than 8+, we can use session variables to simulate the row number:

```
SELECT idx, rn AS rownum
FROM
(
    SELECT idx, @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
    FROM yourTable t, (SELECT @rn := 0) r
    ORDER BY idx DESC
) t
ORDER BY idx;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

On MySQL 8+ we can simply use `ROW_NUBMER` for a much cleaner solution:

```
SELECT idx, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY idx DESC) rownum
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY idx;
```

### Demo

Comment: . . Actually on many pre-8 versions you need to `order by` in a subquery and apply the variables outside.  I think this is part of the optimization to remove support for variables in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You need to order the statement with 'rownum', adding the 'desc' keyword so that the sort is in descending order.

```
select id, rownum 
from <table>
order by rownum desc
```

Comment: Presumably the `rownum` column is not actually part of the original table.